# how to take value from variable inside If Statement in java

Tags: java, android, google-maps, variables

I declared a variable in public class, then I assigned the variable with if statement, but when I calculated it didn't get the value from if statement. How to solve it?
Here the full code https://pastebin.com/yuaMx4Mk Thank You

```
    double doubleJarak=Double.parseDouble(jarak);
    double doublewaktu=Double.parseDouble(waktu);
    //SPinner Code
    MaterialSpinner spinner = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setItems("Premium Rp 7.000", "Pertalite Rp 7.650", "Pertamax Rp 9.850", "Pertamax Turbo Rp 11.200");
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>() {

        @Override public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, String item) {
            //Snackbar.make(view, "Clicked " + item, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(position==0)
                hargaBBM=7000;
            else if(position==1)
                hargaBBM=7650;
            else if(position==2)
                hargaBBM=9850;
            else
                hargaBBM=11200;
        }
    });
    MaterialSpinner spinner2 = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setItems("Honda", "Yamaha", "Kawasaki", "Suzuki", "Lainnya");
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>() {

        @Override public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position2, long id, String item) {
            //Snackbar.make(view, "Clicked " + item + position2, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (position2==0){
                MaterialSpinner spinner3 = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
                spinner3.setItems("Revo 110 FI", "Blade 125 FI", "Supra X 125 FI");
                spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>() {
                    @Override public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, String item) {
                        //Snackbar.make(view, "Clicked " + item, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if(position==0){
                            iritHonda=62200;
                        }else if(position==1){
                            iritHonda=61800;
                        }else if(position==2){
                            iritHonda=61800;
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
    totalHarga=iritHonda*hargaBBM;
    TextView Harga=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalHarga);
    Harga.setText(Double.toString(totalHarga));

}
```

}

Comment: which variable you are looking for?

Comment: iritBBM and hargaBBM pal, in the full code you'll see

Comment: Post a [mcve]. Don't expect people to go look at your full code.

Comment: Put log after your else condition for hargaBBM and same for iritHonda and check in logcat first. if values aren't comes in there, then your item selected method has a problem. Second thing is, you initialize the MaterialSpinner inside item selected which is worst than expected.

Comment: You can't calculate `totalHarga` and display its value there. Nothing's been selected in the `Spinner`s yet. If you want to update the display each time a `Spinner` selection changes, then you need to do your calculation and display in each `onItemSelected()` method. Otherwise, put it in something like a `Button`'s `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake pals, and thank you for you all advice, i'll fix it after this, Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that those functions are callbacks.  They're called asynchronously, after the items are selected.  They do not return a value.  You cannot use the variables they set until after they've actually been called.  That means all your code that uses them at the end of onCreate is in the wrong spot, it needs to be called inside the handler for both spinners (so it can change when either spinner changes).

Comment: oke, i got it. can you tell me how to make chained dropdown with java pal? its very hard when use if statements Thank You for your answer